# When using Observable.merge HTTP requests are never getting called

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I'm trying to loop the http requests using `merge` operator.

**Service:**

```
addData(data) {
    return this.http
        .post(this.url, data)
        .map(resp => {
            return resp;
        });
}
```

**Component:**

```
    addData(data) {
    if (data.length != 0) {
        let respObs: Observable<Response>[] = [];
        data.forEach(element => {
            respObs.push(this.addService.addData(element));
        });
        Observable.merge(respObs)
            .subscribe(resp => {
                console.log(resp); // Observable object not the Response object is getting logged.
            }, err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

**Versions Used:**

Angular: 4.3.5
RxJS: 5.1.0

When the network console is checked I see the http calls were never made and the Observable objects are logged instead of the responses from the http calls.

Comment: Please also mention the versions of Angular and Rxjs you're using.

Comment: Added the versions which I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [**Rxjs 5**](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#merge), you need to pass the Observables as a comma separated list. Try this:

```
Observable.merge(...respObs)
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp); // Observable object not the Response object is getting logged.
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```